# How to add a route to image in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to add link to my logo image.I mean when ever I click my logo image it should redirect to dashboard page.I tried to do it using anchor tag but it is not working properly

```
 <Header className='header' style={{ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }}>
      <div className='header-logo' style={{ width: collapsed ? 80 : 200, height: 0 }}>
        {collapsed &&
        <a href="/dashboard">
          <img src={minLogo} alt='Logo' />
        </a>
        }
        { !collapsed &&
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
        }
      </div>
      <Icon
        className="trigger"
        type={collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
        onClick={this.toggleSideBar}
      />
      <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', float: 'right' }}>
        <Dropdown overlay={menu} placement="bottomRight">
          <Avatar icon='user' />
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    </Header>
```

Comment: are you using react-router ? also what do you mean by its not working properly? do you mean it doesnt navigate properly or is the a tag not rndering?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: @akshay kishore I'm using react-router-dom

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";


<Link to="/dashboard">
    <img src={minLogo} alt='Logo' />
</Link>
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

User router `Link` instead of anchor:

```
    <Link to="/dashboard">
      <img src={minLogo} alt='Logo' />
    </Link>
```